# How to Put set delay on android Progress bar

Tags: android, xml, loading, android-progressbar

What I want is to set it up so that the progress bar loads for 15 seconds, and then go on to the next activity.

Right now the activity has :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btn5 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn5.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();

        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        myIntent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading);

      }        
    });
  }

}
```

And the xml page has:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

I want to know how to make to make progressBar1 Load for 15 seconds and then go to result.xml

Comment: Have a look through all the 'splash screen' Q&A's on StackOverflow, because this is identical in terms of behaviour. Quickest option is probably to post a `Runnable` on a `Handler` with a delay of 15 seconds, that then starts your third `Activity`.

Comment: you can make a separate thread to handle progress bar, give a required delay in thread and then dismiss progress bar...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the progress dialog example in the api demos included with the sample code of the sdk. I believe it is in /src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.java. If you look at the very bottom it has code which updates the progress bar through time delayed messages.

Your question is a bit unclear though, is the code you posted the first or second activity

Comment: I click a button to start this activity, which waits and then opens the third activity, the target.